# When is the prefix non- used vs un-?

Tags: prefixes, negative-prefixes

Specifically, my students were asking why the terms "nonliving" and "undead" are the way they are. (And why "unliving" and "nondead" seem wrong.)

Comment: *Unliving* is what the *undead* do.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undead), you can blame Bram Stoker.

Answer (score 17):

"Un-" is [defined](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/un-) as "a prefix meaning 'not,' freely used as an English formative, **giving negative or opposite force** in adjectives and their derivative adverbs and nouns... and less freely used in certain other nouns."

"Non-" is [defined](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/non-?s=t) as "a prefix meaning 'not,' freely used as an English formative, usually with a simple negative force as **implying mere negation or absence of something (rather than the opposite or reverse of it, as often expressed by un-).**"

So "unchristian" means in some way opposed to Christian virtues, but "non-Christian" just means "not Christian."  "Unprofessional" means not up to professional standards of behavior (not showing up for appointments, say), but "nonprofessional" just means not in a profession.

Logically, then, "non-dead" might mean something like "not having died" (true of rocks and living people), and "undead" might mean "living."  But word constructions don't always make sense.  "Non-dead" isn't a word and "undead" means non-living and supernaturally animated.  Go figure.

Comment: Can we conclude it like `"non-something" is neither "something" nor "unsomething"`?

Comment: I don't think we can.  "Nonbeliever" and "unbeliever" seem close to identical in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Nonliving is more like not intended to be alive than something which is not alive.
Undead is surely alive but it is more towards dead than alive - say If somebody is suffering from illness, you can say he's living undead. In more of negative way You can say he is undead in accident (positively - survived an accident)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Note that we're not like other sites: this is not a forum for posting helpful personal opinion. Instead, we're looking for authoritative, detailed answers backed up by supporting evidence such as references to published sources. Please [edit] your post accordingly. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)